# Проверить существует ли файл на диске в cmd?

Tags: cmd, bat

Я написал следующий скрипт:

```
@echo off
d:
if exist goddamn.txt (
    echo File found.
) else (
    echo File not found.
)
echo -----
pause
```

Но он не проверяет существование файла в папках диска, что мне нужно.
Не подскажете как это реализовать?

Comment: В чем проблема - в поиске файла в подкаталогах?

Comment: B подкаталогах.

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой вариант

```
forfiles /p c:\Directory /s /m goddamn.txt /c "cmd /c @if exist @file (@echo Exists: @path) "
```

P.S. не для "Windows XP", т.к. в поставку не входит forfiles.exe

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
set "fld=d:\"
pushd "%fld%"
dir /s/b/a-d|>nul findstr /c:"goddamn.txt"&&echo file found||echo file not found
popd
pause&exit /b
```

Если требуется список файлов с путями, то ">nul" - просто удалить.

Либо без findstr (что будет точнее для поиска именно файла, а не просто совпадения строки):

```
@echo off
set "fld=d:\"
pushd "%fld%"
>nul 2>&1 dir /b/s/a-d "goddamn.txt"&&echo file found||echo file not found
popd
pause&exit /b
```

Также, если потребуется список файлов с путями, то удалить ">nul 2>&1 " и "&&echo file found||echo file not found"